# RMagick loses the first 8 characters of the file path I am trying to open

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I am using Carrierwave with RMagick in my Ruby on Rails application.
Everything works fine in development, but on my staging environment, I am having some problems.

I tracked it down to what seems to be a problem with RMagick, losing part of the file path being passed to it.  Here is some output from my rails console

```
require 'RMagick'
=> true
# Prove the file exists
File.open('/tmp/logo.png')
=> #<File:/tmp/logo.png> 
# Cant find it with RMagick
Magick::Image::read('/tmp/logo.png').first
=> Magick::ImageMagickError: unable to open file `o.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3698
# Unless I add some characters at the start of my filepath (anything will do)
Magick::Image::read('12345678/tmp/logo.png').first
=>  0x200=>200x100 4634766966517661696x200+100+0 DirectClass 8-bit 6kb
```

I have tried digging into the source code for RMagick, but without much success.  I am hoping that someone can suggest what maybe going wrong.

I have tried recompiling ImageMagick and re-deployed the code several times.
We use rvm, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.2.11 and deploy using Capistrano.

Comment: Have you tried `rvm implode` and reinstalling `rvm` and associated gems? It's probably not ImageMagick that's the issue here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion tadman.  I was holding off anything quite as  serious as imploding anything :-) in the hope of an easier solution.   One of my colleagues found that recompiliing ImageMagick AND THEN reinstalling rmagick gem solved the issue.  Cant seem to add a solution, but that is what worked for me.

Comment: Ah, the old ["Have you tried turning it off and on again"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p85xwZ_OLX0) trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague found the solution -

It was to re-install the rmagick gem.